# Update this formula, and existing formula in production should continue to work :

Tags: formula-field, skill-based-routing

In words/pseudo code, here is the issue:
The updated formula should accommodate the following logic:

Bushel Language on Bushel contact EQUALS German, French, Spanish, Japanese → use this language for routing
Field - Contact.Bushel_Language__c

Bushel Language on Bushel contact NOT EQUAL TO German, French, Spanish, Japanese → use Account Language
Field - TEXT(Account.Language__c)
OR Bushel Language ‘is blank’ → use Account Language
Field - TEXT(Account.Language__c)

current formula -

```
/*Bushel logic (for everyone)*/
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Contact.Bushel_Language__c)),
    IF(
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Account.Language__c)),
        IF(
            CONTAINS(TEXT(Account.Territory_16__c),“EMEIA”), 
            “English - Int”, 
            “English - US”
        ),
        CASE(
            Account.Language__c,
            “English - Int”, “English - Int”,
            “English – Int”, “English - Int”,
            “English -- Int”, “English - Int”,
            “English - US”, “English - US”,
            “English – US”, “English - US”,
            “English -- US”, “English - US”,
            “English”, “English - US”,
            Contact.Bushel_Language__c
        )
    ),
    /*EMEIA logic (non Bushel)*/
    IF(
        (Account.region_geo__c = “EMEIA”),
        IF(
            ISBLANK(TEXT(Contact.Preferred_Language__c)), 
            “English - Int”,
            CASE(
                Contact.Preferred_Language__c,
                “English”, “English - Int”,
                “English - US”, “English - Int”,
                “English – US”, “English - US”,
                “English -- US”, “English - Int”,
                “English – Int”, “English - Int”,
                “English -- Int”, “English - Int”,
                TEXT(Contact.Preferred_Language__c)
            )
        ),
        /*All other regions logic (non Bushel)*/
        IF(
            NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Contact.Preferred_Language__c))),
            CASE(
                Contact.Preferred_Language__c,
                “English”, “English - US”,
                “English - US”, “English - US”,
                “English – US”, “English - US”,
                “English -- US”, “English - US”,
                “English - Int”, “English - Int”,
                “English – Int”, “English - Int”,
                “English -- Int”, “English - Int”,
                TEXT(Contact.Preferred_Language__c)
            ),
            TEXT(Account.Language__c)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting your formula according to best practices (single "statement" per line, indent like it's code). Also, if you haven't done so already, you will need to get rid of those "smart" quotes. Formulas require either single or double quotes, and will give you errors if you try to use "smart" quotes.

Comment: Also, a note for others: The differences in the `CASE()` arguments are down to the hard-to-see differences between hypens, en-dashes, and em-dashes.